Copy blob is not working in Azure logic app getting 404 ResourceNotFound error
I have created logic app trigger which moves blob from source to destination location in storage account container.
Created a api connection to storage account using access key to connect with storage account and also assigned a role storage contributor by enabling system assigned managed identity in logic app. And container 'X' access level changes to private(no anonymous access).
when tried running the logic app, it is getting failed with status code 404 ResourceNotFound error.
But same logic app is running successfully when container 'X' access level changes to Container(anonymous read access for container and blobs).
configured Storage account is allowed to access all networks.
As per my understanding we have give the required access permission but still unable to access the container when it is marked access level as Private.

Are you using Consumption plan or standard ?

Consumption plan

For Consumption Plan you can follow below steps:
Add Logic app as an  exception, Add resource type as Microsoft.Logic/workflows and then name:

Then you can use below design and I am using both containers as private:

Output:

